# Android - asking for GPS permissions Context.getTheme()' null object reference

Tags: android, android-context, user-permissions, android-gps

I use location in my app and on first install the app is asking the users to allow location on their devices.

Everything works fine if they press OK (enable the location). But if they decline, the app crashes with this error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference

Here is part of my code related to this error:

```
     if (permissionsRejected.size() > 0) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissionsRejected.get(0))) {
                            showMessageOKCancel("These permissions are mandatory for the application. Please allow access.",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                requestPermissions(permissionsRejected.toArray(
                                                        new String[permissionsRejected.size()]), ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

and also:

```
            private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
```

The error is pointing on showMessageOKCancel.

I think there may be some issue with context, which I have here: new AlertDialog.Builder(context)

So I tried to add:

```
private final Context mContext;
```

and inside the private void showMessageOKCancel I put 
    `this.mContext = context;` and finally `new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)`

but i have still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally, this helped in my case:

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert)
```

Works fine!

Answer (score 1):

if you used extends AppCompatActivity then only pass this keyword it also work and used Fragment then pass getActivity() in alert dialog i test below code in mainactiviy extends Appcompatactivity and it working not getting any error.

```
    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this) // if fragment pass getActivity()
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();
}
```

Comment: I am using fragment. When I try to use this.getActivity() or this.getContext() then I have this error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme. I really don't want to change my theme, because the actionbar and everything is set already

Comment: you check your styles.xml file and add this line in style     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">